# CharacterController collision issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, collision-detection, game-physics

I have added an ability to crouch in the game. The way I've done that is by changing the controller height and center y value. The issue is when I crouch to go underneath a platform the player still collides with the platform even though there's clearly enough space.
[image]

If I set the controller height to the crouch height as the default height the player is able to go underneath the platform without trouble. Although, if I use the center offset the collision issue occurs.

```
bool isCrouching; float defaultHeight; Vector3 localCameraPos;

private CharacterController controller = null;
private Camera camera;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    camera = camera.main;
    localCameraPos = camera.transform.localPosition;
    defaultHeight = controller.height;
}
void Update()
{
    isCrouching = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    DoCrouch();
}
void DoCrouch()
{
    var height = isCrouching ? defaultHeight / 2 : defaultHeight;

    controller.height = Mathf.Lerp(controller.height, height, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    controller.center = Vector3.down * (defaultHeight - controller.height) / 2.0f;

    var camPos = new Vector3(0, camera.transform.localPosition.y, 0);
    camPos.y = Mathf.Lerp(camPos.y, localCameraPos.y - (defaultHeight - controller.height), 5 * Time.deltaTime);

    camera.transform.localPosition = camPos + localCameraPos;
}
```

The player moves by calling CharacterController.move() function.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    isWalking = !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);

    Vector2 _inputVector = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

    if (_inputVector.sqrMagnitude > 1) { _inputVector.Normalize(); }

    Vector3 desireMoveDir = transform.right * _inputVector.x;
    desireMoveDir += transform.forward * _inputVector.y;

    if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, controller.radius, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, controller.height / 2f, 1))
    {
        desireMoveDir = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desireMoveDir, hit.normal).normalized;
    }

    moveDirection = desireMoveDir * MoveSpeed;

    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

How do I fix this issue? Thank you

Comment: you could access the collider and scale also it?

Comment: I don't think changing the scale is a good idea. I would need to have a pivot at the bottom of the controller, so would need to add an empty game object and have a controller as a child and considering that I move the player by calling a CharacterController.Move() this wouldn't work, cause the child would move on its own. And not having a parent and just scaling the controller would result in jittering, that's why I'm using center offset when changing the height. Also changing the scale would mess with the child objects, like a flashlight, which is a child of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just solved the problem. I had a **step offset** set to 0.7. Changing it to 0, fixed the problem. Only took me two days...nice